# To encode trailing space with something like {U+0020}

Tags: vimrc

How could I encode space in .vimrc? This is required here:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:→\ ,
```

As you see, I use comma to workaround this issue, but I want something like

```
set list
set listchars=tab:→{U+0020}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to just use a literal space.

Simply use `execute`:

```
execute 'set listchars=tab:> '
```

Or, as [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) points out in the [comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/to-encode-trailing-space-with-something-like-u0020/18759?noredirect=1#comment32367_18759):

> Alternatively, you can use `let &listchars="tab:>\u0020"`, see `:h expr-quote`

---

Note that unicode sequences may be entered via `<C-v>` if it is followed by a 0, x, or other specifiers (they determine the « format » of the following code).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `let &listchars="tab:>\u0020"`, see `:h expr-quote`